# GVP(PP) orbital energies?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, theoretical-chemistry, ab-initio

Hartree-Fock orbital energies can be interpreted physically, e.g. in Koopmans theorem, while one cannot assign active MCSCF orbitals to energies in general. What about GVB, say for example GVB(PP) orbitals, does it make sense to assign energies to those?